# Undefined reference to InitGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, undefined-reference, glew

Thing is, I am trying to compile simple C++/OpenGL code and no matter what I keep getting this from compiler:

```
/tmp/ccU7u7eO.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `initGL()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `loadMedia()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `handleKeys(unsigned char, int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `render()'
```

and I compile it with these:
g++ main.cpp -o test -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lglut

Comment: Have you tried enabling experimental mode for GLEW? I don't think initGL nor handleKeys are GL functions, if they're your functions perhaps you might want to check if you've defined them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Undefined reference to 'x'` just means the compiler cannot find a symbol by that name.

Common causes include:

- Missing a library
- Forgot to include a file in your compiler / linker command if you have multiple source files in the project.
- A typo / misspelling of a function name, e.g. you typed `initGL` when you really meant `InitGL`.

This is the best I can do without you posting the rest of your code.